# Getting a value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an PHP array parsed from a JSON string that looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["ResultSet"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["version"]=>
    string(3) "1.0"
    ["Error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["ErrorMessage"]=>
    string(8) "No error"
    ["Locale"]=>
    string(5) "us_US"
    ["Quality"]=>
    int(99)
    ["Found"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Results"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(29) {
        ["quality"]=>
        int(72)
        ["latitude"]=>
        string(9) "34.746479"
        ["longitude"]=>
        string(10) "-92.289589"
        ["offsetlat"]=>
        string(9) "34.746479"
        ["offsetlon"]=>
        string(10) "-92.289589"
        ["radius"]=>
        int(500)
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "34.746479,-92.289589"
        ["line1"]=>
        string(13) "State Capitol"
        ["line2"]=>
        string(22) "Little Rock, AR  72201"
        ["line3"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["line4"]=>
        string(13) "United States"
        ["house"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["street"]=>
        string(13) "State Capitol"
        ["xstreet"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["unittype"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["unit"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["postal"]=>
        string(5) "72201"
        ["neighborhood"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["city"]=>
        string(11) "Little Rock"
        ["county"]=>
        string(14) "Pulaski County"
        ["state"]=>
        string(8) "Arkansas"
        ["country"]=>
        string(13) "United States"
        ["countrycode"]=>
        string(2) "US"
        ["statecode"]=>
        string(2) "AR"
        ["countycode"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["hash"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["woeid"]=>
        int(12789127)
        ["woetype"]=>
        int(11)
        ["uzip"]=>
        string(5) "72201"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am trying to get the value of the woeid parameter like this:

```
 foreach ($data["ResultSet"] as $key => $val) 
 {
    echo $val["woeid"]."<br />";
 }
```

But for some reason it isn't getting the value.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that that's what your JSON string looks like. Especially since it's not a string at all.

Comment: try $data["ResultSet"]["woeid"]

Comment: Take a look here. I outputed it to the screen: http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/city.php?country_id=1&country_name=&state_id=5&state_name=Arkansas&city_id=2127&city_name=Little%20Rock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `$data['ResultSet']['Results']`, not `$data['ResultSet']`

Answer (score 0):

The first `$key => $val` will be `version => 1.0`. The strong `1.0` isn't an array and does't have a woeid.

I'm not going to try to decode your single line expression of a huge data structure, but you need to navigate to the point where the data you want actually appears.

Comment: Yeah but in my loop, it outputs every row of the array, and the woeid is still not outputted for some reason.

Comment: Look at the source view of the document. Then you get indentation. You want to loop over the Results, not the ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

$data["ResultSet"] is an object, the actual results are in $data["ResultSet"]["Results"]. So use:

```
 foreach ($data["ResultSet"]["Results"] as $key => $val) 
 {
    echo $val["woeid"]."<br />";
 }
```